# Internet is not getting connected in android

Tags: android

I have created an app in android and it requires some data to be transfered over internet. I have written the codes but I don't see any data transfer on my device. Am I missing any point? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add permissions in the android Manifest file in order to have internet connection. Did you add these codes in android manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
```